# populating dropdown list in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu

i have a dropdownlist that populates from the sql server database. populating the list is not a problem, but does anyone know how to populate the value part of the listitem.

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="colors">
<listitem value="1">black</listitem>
<listitem value="2">blue</listitem>
<listitem value="3">orange</listitem>
<listitem value="4">red</listitem>
<listitem value="5">violet</listitem>
```

how do you populate the value=1,2,3,4,5 when you're populating from table in database?

Comment: how is it duplicate? because it is about dropdowns???

Comment: @casperOne, I disagree, this is not a duplicate.  for starters he's asking about VB and not C#, second you example is about getting the DataTextField from properties, where @ugio's question is about getting the DataValueField from a database.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: Yeah, it pretty much is.  First, what he is talking about is not language-specific.  It's part of the .NET framework.  Second, he has to materialize those results in some way, and that way is through a data member that is exposed either through a data set, typed data set, LINQ-to-SQL/Entities object, etc, etc.  Regardless, the question is about data binding, not about getting values from a database.

Comment: my question is about populating the value in lisitem. so whoever knows how to do that using the while loop that i have please explain

Comment: do you have values already populated in the dropdownlist?  Is this why you want to add to the list using a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to build your select statement

```
Select [ID], [Value] From [Table]
```

You would store your query into a variable (I use "r" for return)
Then you need to attach it to the dropdown

```
DropDownList1.DataTextField = r.Value
DropDownList1.DataValueField = r.ID
DropDownList1.Databind()
```

If you really REALLY need to loop, then try something along these lines (not code is not checked, just a general idea.)

```
For Each o as object in r
  DropDownList1.Items.Insert(o.ID,new ListItem(o.Value,o.ID))
Next
```

Or with the DataReader (again, untested, but prolly close)

```
While DataReader.Read()
  DropDownList1.Items.Insert(datareader("value"),new ListItem(datareader("name"),datareader("value"))
End While
```

Comment: will this work in a loop? i have sql datareader with a while loop. this is current code -
sql = "select id, colors from tbl_colors"
...
dropdownlist1.items.add = datareader("colors" & "")
end while

Comment: I would recommend NOT looping if you don't have to.  Databind is more efficient.

Comment: well i have numerous records that come from the database depending on the sql query, so i thought looping with while in a datareader was the right thing to do. so is there no solution but to change the code, or can i work with my existing loop?

Comment: see my edit above.  It's prolly not bang on since I'm not sitting in front of a IDE, but it's close.

Comment: Another option might be to loop through your records and add them to your own custom object, then bind your DropDownList to the custom Object.

Comment: see i did that. dropdownlist.items.add(datareader("name","value")
and the result i got was Black1, blue2 ... as concatenated

Comment: I used Items.Insert, not Items.Add.  You also need to add it DropDownList1.Items.Insert(datareader("value"),new ListItem(datareader("name"),datareader("value"))... or something like that

Comment: getting close to my 1000 goal... shootin for the end of the weekend ;)

Comment: how do i become better in vb.net? i need to work on it evreyday, so i wanna be really good at it

Comment: It all depends on how deep you want to go.  If this is a career and your full time job... you'll prolly want to go to school.  If you want to do it on your own... Google is your friend.  Come up with an idea or a challenge and work your way through it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an IList implementation which you are binding the data objects to (you seem to have the results materialized in *something* already, as you say you can populate the text), what you need to do is specify the *name* of the property/member on your instances returned from your IList implementation.

So, assuming that you have a DataTable with columns of ID and Value, or an IList of objects that was populated from LINQ-to-SQL/Entities, each with an ID property and a Value property, you would do this:

```
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID"
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Value"
```

You need to set it to the names of the fields as opposed to the *values*, as the binding mechanism uses the property descriptor framework to figure out how to map those strings to the properties/columns which contain the data.