# dropdownlistfor fill values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, entity-framework, drop-down-menu

I have a table T with fields id, `parentid`, name. i make relationship with own table so parentid=>id one to many, so if `parentid=null` it is a parent record, and if `parentid` not null it is child record.

After mapping I have class with 2 new properties- T1 (Collection of T) and T2 (Instance of T)

How can I fill `dropdownlistfor` if I don't have field `parentid` filled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the ID field for the DataValueField.  That way it's always unique... or am I missing something?

Comment: can you give examle? i try
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.ParentMenu.Id,Model) %> but it give error
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<mrhome.Models.Menu>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Check out the answer I gave earlier tonight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346381/populating-dropdown-list-in-vb-net/2346395#2346395