# Convert dropdownlist value to string

Tags: vb.net, linq, html-select

I have two tables in my db, `Building` and `Rooms`.  I am using two dropdownlists.  The aim is to have the first dropdownlist, `ddlBuilding`, for selecting a building name.  When the name is selected I want to query the database to find only room numbers that correspond to that building and return them in the room dropdownlist, `ddlRoomNumber`.
For example:

Building A has rooms 1, 2 and 3.
Building B has rooms 4, 5 and 6.

If the user selects building A from `ddlBuilding` they should only be presented with rooms 1, 2 and 3 in `ddlRoomNumber`

I have set up a query to do this but I am getting an error to say that dropdownlist cannot be converted to string.  The code in question is:

```
  Protected Sub txtRoomNumber_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtRoomNumber.TextChanged

    Dim db As New OrionDataClassesDataContext

    Dim roomNumber = (From build In db.Buildings Join rm In db.Rooms On build.Building_code Equals rm.Building_code
                      Where build.Building_name = ddlBuilding
                      Select rm.Room_Number).distint

    ddlRoomNumber.DataSource = roomNumber
    ddlRoomNumber.DataBind()

End Sub
```

It is the line `where build.Building_name = ddlBuilding` that is causing  the error.  Any thoughts on how I can pull the string out of the dropdownlist and use it to validate my query.

I have changed the code to the follow after some responses and research.  It is still not working.  `ddlRoomNumber` is not binding to my query.

```
Protected Sub ddlRoomNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlRoomNumber.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim db As New OrionDataClassesDataContext


    ddlRoomNumber.DataSource = (From build In db.Buildings Join rm In db.Rooms On build.Building_code Equals rm.Building_code
                                Where (build.Building_name = ddlBuilding.SelectedItem.Text)
                                Select rm.Room_Number, rm.Room_ID)

    ddlRoomNumber.DataTextField = "Room_Number"
    ddlRoomNumber.DataValueField = "Room_ID"
    ddlRoomNumber.DataBind()
End Sub
```

This is the asp page.  Is there any way to type in the linq datasource to point it to my vb query.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRoomNumber" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                           </asp:dropdownlist>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ddlBuilding.SelectedItem.Text` instead of `ddlBuilding`

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  Thanks.  I'm trying to test it now but for some reason the dropdownlist `ddlRoomNumber` is marked as unbound.  Surely the last two lines of my code should be binding the query to the list no?  Are there alternatives to binding my query?

Comment: you can try to bind like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346381/populating-dropdown-list-in-vb-net

Comment: I do not know what's going on.  I've tried several different binding methods at this stage, included what you linked me to.  I am 99% sure I'm typing sensible code but it just will not bind to my ddl.  Any ideas?  The code I am currently running with is:

Comment: i don't actually get any error.  When I look at the ddl it is simply not bound.  I will edit my original question to include the code I am working from now

Comment: you can put a breakpoint in the code and see if any data comes to datasource.

Comment: i should add that i'm a novice and don't know how to debug.  I have checked several different sources now and what i am typing it seems to fit exactly to what others type.  Could it be anything to do with the method header or how the query is being declared?  The head is:

Protected Sub ddlBuilding_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlBuilding.SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: head is correct but you can try something like `ddlRoomNumber.DataSource = db.Rooms.ToList()` and see if the problem is in the query

Comment: Nope, still not binding to the list.  Am I right in thinking that when I write a query in vb and perform the `databind()` then it should just automatically pick up the ddl without me having to specify anything in the aspx page?  Thanks for your help here btw

Comment: yes, databind is doing all work. but i really dont see anything wrong in the code.